# Package not found when create data source using camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, camel-jdbc

I tried to replicate the same example given in the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19357395/how-to-create-datasource-using-camel).

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;    
import org.apache.camel.main.Main;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;

public class JDBCExample {

    private Main main;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JDBCExample example = new JDBCExample();
        example.boot();
    }

    public void boot() throws Exception {
        // create a Main instance
        main = new Main();
        // enable hangup support so you can press ctrl + c to terminate the JVM
        main.enableHangupSupport();

        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@MYSERVER:1521:myDB";
        DataSource dataSource = setupDataSource(url);

        // bind dataSource into the registery
        main.bind("myDataSource", dataSource);

        // add routes
        main.addRouteBuilder(new MyRouteBuilder());

        // run until you terminate the JVM
        System.out.println("Starting Camel. Use ctrl + c to terminate the JVM.\n");
        main.run();
    }

    class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
        public void configure() {
            String dst = "C:/Local Disk E/TestData/Destination";
            from("direct:myTable")
               .setBody(constant("select * from myTable"))
               .to("jdbc:myDataSource")
                .to("file:" + dst);
        }
    }

    private DataSource setupDataSource(String connectURI) {
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        ds.setUsername("sa");
        ds.setPassword("devon1");
        ds.setUrl(connectURI);
        return ds;
    }
}
```

I have included the camel-jdbc-3.0.1.jar and my db specific jar file in my class path.

When I try to compile the code using the following command

```
javac -cp .;D:\Code\bin JDBCExample.java
```

I am getting the following error.

```
JDBCExample.java:2: error: package org.apache.camel.main does not exist
import org.apache.camel.main.Main;
                            ^
JDBCExample.java:3: error: package org.apache.camel.builder does not exist
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
                               ^
JDBCExample.java:4: error: package org.apache.commons.dbcp does not exist
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
```

Where am I going wrong? I tried adding camel-core to the classpath, but it didn't help.

Kindly let me know your thoughts, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did well by adding camel-core to your classpath, but camel-core and camel-jdbc do not suffice, you should also add the following dependencies:

> JDBCExample.java:2: error: package org.apache.camel.main does not exist
>   import org.apache.camel.main.Main;

Add **camel-main** dependency

> JDBCExample.java:4: error: package org.apache.commons.dbcp does not exist
>   import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;

Add **commons-dbcp** dependency

> JDBCExample.java:3: error: package org.apache.camel.builder does not exist
>   import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

Add **camel-core** dependency

With these and the **camel-jdbc** dependency, you are good to go.

I suggest that you use maven to handle your dependencies (and much more) if you can... If you have not used it before this [five minutes quickstart](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) will gently introduce you to it.

Here is a sample pom.xml that resolves all these dependencies correctly

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>demo</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-jdbc-demo</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>camel-jdbc-demo</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-main -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-main</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Your suggestion helped.  Thanks.